# Multiple component picker view

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I am working on project with picker view. I have two components in it. I want to have the second component contents loaded based the selection made in the first view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:` and `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` when called for the second component will have to check the value of the first component to determine what to return.

`pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` when called for the first component will have to call `reloadComponent:` on the picker to tell it to reload the data for the second component.

Comment: Could you please explain little more in detail.